# VAADIN 7: Image from byte array works only once

Tags: arrays, image, byte, vaadin

This is a follow up of [How to upload an image using ByteArrayOutputStream in Vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979896/how-to-upload-an-image-using-bytearrayoutputstream-in-vaadin)

I put the code from there into my app. However, the inner part of the 
overridden  getStream() is called only once and on the next image change attempt, no more. The code outside is executed. No statics used.

```
final byte [] imageBytes =  beanItem.getPicture(); // a byte []
 StreamSource streamSource = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() {
        System.out.println(">>>> streamResource:getStream called.size:" + imageBytes.length);
        return (imageBytes == null) ? null : new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        }
};

  StreamResource imageResource = new StreamResource(streamSource, "");
  image.setSource (imageResource);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Gerry

Comment: Check this another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will check it tomorrow.  I wonder if the solution of the referred thread will be applicable as shown in the above fragment, the stream is fully re-created on each call. 
Perhaps the stream consuming image is not able to detect that a new stream is loaded and thereby sees no need to call the stream again.

Comment: How do you call this piece of code? Do you have it inside a `ValueChangedListener` or in a `ClickListener` ?

Comment: @Niby: Yes, exactly a 'valueChangeListener' in a table.